# Let's get critical: Aug 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Musical Practice & Performance Stack Exchange](http://music.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://music.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How to enter overlapping notes in Sibelius 7](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/11343/how-to-enter-overlapping-notes-in-sibelius-7)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [What purpose do accidentals serve in music?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/11159/what-purpose-do-accidentals-serve-in-music)

  **Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Returning shine to very old silver flute?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/11230/returning-shine-to-very-old-silver-flute)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [What are the greek modes, and how do they differ from modern modes?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/11274/what-are-the-greek-modes-and-how-do-they-differ-from-modern-modes)

  **Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [practice of omitting notes in jazz piano](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/11315/practice-of-omitting-notes-in-jazz-piano)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [How can you teach a child the names of the notes on each key on a keyboard?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/11432/how-can-you-teach-a-child-the-names-of-the-notes-on-each-key-on-a-keyboard)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [How far do the supporting chords contribute to the tonality of Vi Hart's "Twinkle Twinkle Little Star", and if they do, how?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/11178/how-far-do-the-supporting-chords-contribute-to-the-tonality-of-vi-harts-twinkl)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How should I mic a violin in a live concert?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/11246/how-should-i-mic-a-violin-in-a-live-concert)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Tonality and Modality together](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/11358/tonality-and-modality-together)

  **Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [Instrumental Live Performance](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/11187/instrumental-live-performance)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the most important consideration for getting this site out of beta is having more questions asked and one way to do that is to have enough questions answered here so that people who have questions see this site as a place to go for answers.  I would suggest (but not sure if this is acceptable) that people who have higher reputation seed the site with questions they had when they were studying music and then give answers that they've learned.  In other words, get a big enough knowledge bank here that people turn to it for problems.  I might ask a number of questions about notation ("How are complex tuplets, like 2 in the place of 3, not 3 in the place of 2, notated?") and then give an answer. Is this something the site wants to encourage?

Comment: Yes, "it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged" on Stack Exchange http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: Good idea. It works for things you've just learned, too: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/9502/how-do-tape-wound-strings-compare-to-metal-flatwounds